# ECC alternative for real time RAM error checking/handling?

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, motherboard, ecc

I had 2 days of labor lost when compiling and getting errors. I finally ran memtest and found that one of my 6 year old stick of GSKILL ram had errors(by the way... they never replied to the RMA lifetime warranty request).

I'm building a new desktop system(non gaming...mainly for dev and web hosting).

I really want to get ECC ram this time. But I also want to get the intel i5-7500T because it's low wattage, but it does not support ECC. AMD does offer ECC, but they run hotter/has higher wattage than I would like.

I don't see myself rebooting and running memtest as a routine to be proactive. I can't use registered ram because most desktop motherboards do not support registered/buffer ram.

Is there a ECC alternative for real time RAM error handling/checking?

Comment: "by the way... they never replied to the RMA warranty request)" - You attempted to request an RMA after 6 years?  Most memory comes with a year warranty at most.

Comment: What exactly is your objective? Having ECC RAM doesn't magically protect you from bad RAM modules...

Comment: No but at least you are told when they happen... The original IBM PC had parity checking (better than nothing, even if not as good as ECC...)

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator - Actually ECC ram can both correct 1 bit errors and detect >1 bit errors, so it's quite useful here

Comment: @davidgo I'm not suggesting it's not useful, but the OP has complained his RAM is bad, suggesting he may expect ECC to resolve more than transient errors. Rather than assume his expectation, I thought it better to ask...

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator in addition  to correcting errors, I am able to view a realtime log of ECC errors. This allows me write a script for real time alerts sent to me.

Comment: @Ramhound this ram has a lifetime warranty.

Comment: You want ECC RAM, but you don’t want a motherboard that supports ECC RAM. Seems counterproductive to me.

Comment: @Appleoddity nothing is stated about me not wanting ECC motherboard. What I stated is I want a low wattage CPU that Intel offers but AMD does not

Comment: Ahh yes. I misunderstood you were describing a CPU and not a motherboard. With all the things that can go wrong I’m not sure ECC RAM is very beneficial. RAM rarely ever goes bad, that’s why most of it has a lifetime warranty. If you want reliability, then go all the way and get yourself a server board, Xeon processor, and ECC ram. I just don’t see the point in the trouble over this for something that is almost never a problem because you had a bad experience. I’m unaware of any equivalent alternatives you could use.